# Quiero realizar un contador y me figura el siguiente error TypeError: missing 1 required positional argument:

Tags: python, funciones, class

Estoy iniciándome en *Python* y haciendo un ejercicio de práctica no consigo que funcione el método `contar_repetidos`. Actualmente lo que necesito es que pasándole una lista de números, el código pueda correr con dicha lista.

Este es mi código:

```python
class Funcionesmat2:

    def __init__(self, listado_numeros):
        self.listado = listado_numeros

    def comprobar_primos(self):
        for i in self.listado:
            if (self.__comprobar_primos(i)):
                print('El número',i,'si es un número primo')
            else:
                print('El elemento',i,'no es un número primo')
    
    def conversor_grados(self, grados_origen, grados_destino):
        for i in self.listado:
            print(i,'grados',grados_origen,'son',self.__conversor_grados(i, grados_origen,grados_destino),'grados',grados_destino)

    def factorizador(self):
        for i in self.listado:
            print('El factorial de',i,'es',self.__factorizador(i))
    
    def __comprobar_primos (self, numero):
        num_primo = True
        for i in range (2, numero):
            if (numero % i == 0):
                num_primo = False
                break
        return num_primo

    def contar_repetidos(self, valores):
        num_repetido = 0
        repeticiones = 0
        for numero in valores:
            num_rept = valores.count(numero)
            if num_rept > repeticiones:
                repeticiones = num_rept
                num_repetido = numero
        return num_repetido, repeticiones

    def __conversor_grados (self, grados, grados_origen, grados_destino):
        if grados_origen == 'Celsius':
            if (grados_destino == 'Celsius'):
                valor_destino1 = grados
            elif grados_destino == 'Farenheit':
                valor_destino1 = grados * 1.8 + 32
            elif grados_destino == 'Kelvin':
                valor_destino1 = grados + 273.15
    
        elif grados_origen == 'Farenheit':
            if (grados_destino == 'Farenheit'):
                valor_destino1 = grados
            elif grados_destino == 'Celsius':
                valor_destino1 = (grados - 32) * 1.8
            elif grados_destino == 'Kelvin':
                valor_destino1 = ((grados - 32) / 1.8 + 273.15)
    
        elif grados_origen == 'Kelvin':
            if (grados_destino == 'Kelvin'):
                valor_destino1 = grados
            elif grados_destino == 'Celsius':
                valor_destino1 = grados - 273.15
            elif grados_destino == 'Farenheit':
                valor_destino1 = ((grados - 273.15) * 1.8) + 32

        return valor_destino1

    def __factorizador(self, facto):
        factorizable = 1
        if (type(facto) != int):
            resultado = print('El número tiene que ser un núemro entero')

        elif facto < 0:
            resultado = print('El número no puede ser 0 o menor que 0')

        elif facto > 0:
            while facto > 0:
                factorizable = factorizable * facto 
                facto -= 1
                resultado = factorizable
    
        return resultado

yy = Funcionesmat2([1,1,4,1,5,6,6,6,8,7])
num_repetido, repeticiones = g.contar_repetidos ()
print('El valor modal es', num_repetido, 'y se reptie', repeticiones, 'veces')
```

El error que me sale es el siguiente:

> TypeError: contar_repetidos() missing 1 required positional argument:
> 'valores'

Comment: la función `contar_repetidos(valores)` requiere que le pases un argumento y no le estás pasando ninguno.

Comment: Sucede que le paso una lista de números de donde tomar los valores `yy = Funcionesmat2([1,1,4,1,5,6,6,6,8,7])` y no utiliza dicha lista

Comment: En tu código `num_repetido, repeticiones = g.contar_repetidos()` 1. Desconocemos quien es `g`, 2. no le estas pasando el parametro `valores` a la función contar_repetidos().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como comentó @CandidMoe, la función `contar_repetidos()` de la clase `Funcionesmat2` necesita 1 parametro (`valores`) para poder darte el resultado deseado.

Estas utilizando una instancia de tu clase Funcionesmat2 almacenada en la variable `g` (desconozco la finalidad ya que no colocaste esa variable en tu código)

Para que esto funcione debes modificar el llamado a la función y agregar el argumento faltante:

PD: Dudo que sea el enfoque, pero igual te dejo la modificación

```python
g = Funcionesmat2([1, 1, 4, 1, 5, 6, 6, 6, 8, 7])
yy = Funcionesmat2([3, 3, 7, 3, 4, 6, 6, 9, 8, 7])
num_repetido, repeticiones = g.contar_repetidos(yy.listado)
print('El valor modal es', num_repetido, 'y se repite', repeticiones, 'veces')
```

---

Este si creo que sea el enfoque deseado, ya que estas utilizando la misma instancia de la clase para acceder a su función y hacer el conteo de los números

```python
yy = Funcionesmat2([3, 3, 7, 3, 4, 6, 6, 9, 8, 7])
num_repetido, repeticiones = yy.contar_repetidos(yy.listado)
print('El valor modal es', num_repetido, 'y se repite', repeticiones, 'veces')
```

---

Pero inclusive puedes hacer algo mejor, haciendo uso del listado dentro de la misma clase sin la necesidad de pasarlo como argumento de la función empleando `self`:

```python
class Funcionesmat2:
    def __init__(self, listado_numeros):
        self.listado = listado_numeros

    # TODOS TUS OTROS METODOS.......
    
    # EL METODO A MODIFICAR
    def contar_repetidos(self):
        num_repetido = 0
        repeticiones = 0
        for numero in self.listado:   # <------ ACA
            num_rept = self.listado.count(numero) # <------ ACA
            if num_rept > repeticiones:
                repeticiones = num_rept
                num_repetido = numero
        return num_repetido, repeticiones
```

Por aca te dejo el playground https://www.online-python.com/IXDQz3jsxm

Comment: Gracias @GmrYael recién estoy comenzando con esto y a veces se me complican ciertas cosas. La variable `g` no iba allí me confundí jaja. Pero con tu sugerencia ya pude hacer que corra como es debido.